# i need subdomain on umbraco website

Tags: subdomain, umbraco

I need to know if i can install a subdomain like dyndns or no-ip.I create a website for my school so they need to test it first somewere online.What can i do?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please - do you want the Umbraco site to show different content on your subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is yes, at least if I understand the question.

Say you already have www.example.com working with umbraco site, you create the dns records so that mytestsite.example.com maps to the same ip address.

You then need to bind (in IIS) mytestsite.example.com to the same place as the 'main' site so that either url will get you to the same umbraco site.

Last thing you do go into the umbraco admin module and right click on the 'test content' page and select the 'manage hostnames' option in umbraco to tell umbraco which set of content to load for depending on what url was being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a second site, but just need to have the (future) live site on a beta address, you can simply map the mytestsite.example.com URL in IIS to that website.  Then when you want to go live, just change the mapping to www.example.com.

Here are a couple of articles on that:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/bindings/binding

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Stick to the GUI method of setting it.

If you do actually need multiple sites, then E.J.'s method above is correct.